# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'checkState' in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Good day. I'm working on a project that uses QListWidget. I kept getting this error that the method I was using returns a NoneType, but when I use print() it clearly returns something. Sorry for the bad English, but here's the code:

```
for i in range(0, self.listUndone.count()):
    itemStatus = self.listUndone.item(i).checkState()
    print(itemStatus) #outputs 0 if not checked, outputs 2 if checked
    if itemStatus == Qt.Checked:
        string = "'" + self.listUndone.item(i).text() + "'"
        c.execute(f"UPDATE todo SET status = 'DONE' WHERE tasks = {string}")
        self.listUndone.takeItem(i)
        item = QListWidgetItem(tasks[i][0])
        item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
        self.listDone.addItem(item)
```

and here is the output...

```
0
2
0
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'checkState'
```

Comment: The problem is that you're removing items from `listUndone` inside the for-loop. `self.listUndone.takeItem(i)` removes an item from the loop, which decreases `self.listUndone.count()` by 1. However, the `range` is never updated to reflect the changes, so it will go outside of the list's boundaries.

Comment: You should use another method of iteration. It's never good to iterate over an array while adding / removing items from it. You never know wether the item is appended at the end, or at the start. Or if the list is sorted after inserting / removing data.

Comment: First create the list of items, then iterate it: `items = [self.listUndone.item(i) for i in range (self.listUndone.count())]` `for item in items: ...`. Alternatively, loop in recursive order and use `insertItem()`.

Comment: Ohhh, i solved the problem by removing the line with the takeItem() method. Thank y'all for the response, I learned something new 